# "Incorrect" app id when adding platform to Facebook Developer Account

Tags: facebook, app-store, app-store-connect

I have some strange issues with my app, or more like adding the app to my developer facebook account. I have created and added app-ads.txt to my website domain and it checks out and is verified.
The same id that is in the file, is the same one on appstore connect, fails me when using it in the app id field.

[image]

What am I doing wrong?
The error message I receive is:

> Something went wrong with retrieving your iPhone Store ID. Please make
> sure the app has been publicly available in the App Store for at least
> 24 hours. For apps with IDs in countries outside the US, you may need
> to wait up to a week before the ID becomes available.

To be clear, our app has been up and running for a few months.